# Performance Oracle client 11gR2 on Windows 10

Tags: oracle11g, windows-10, database-performance, oracleclient

We have an Oracle 11.2.0.4 database running on a database server. Computers connect to this database trough the oracle client 11g R2.

After migrating Windows 7 laptops to Windows 10 laptops, we've noticed some performance issues on the new laptops with Windows 10. The problem isn't inside the application, nor in the network between them. This has already been checked by the supplier of the application and our network team.

Can it be that Oracle client 11g2 R2 isn't working well with Windows 10? Or can't this be the issue?
I can't find anything on the internet stating that this version of oracle client isn't 100% compatible with Windows 10.

If someone has some input, it would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance !

Greetings.

Comment: StackOverflow is the wrong site to ask this; you should be on https://dba.stackexchange.com or https://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a specific version of an Oracle client causing performance problems, but I can imagine many situations where *migrating* clients could cause problems if one of the tnsnames.ora, sqlnet.ora, or glogin.sql files was not moved or configured correctly. Check those files for any differences, and make sure that the new clients are correctly referencing the right file locations.

Also, what desktop program is using the client? Check that program's configuration. For example, if you're using Oracle SQL Developer, maybe the new installation is using the Thin JDBC driver instead of the thick OCI driver.